# Jobs in queue does not delay

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-10

Dispatched job didn't work instead it processed the jobs immediately without any delays even though I changed the connection from sync to in .env file:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

```
    <?php
    
    use App\Jobs\MyJob;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    Route::get('/', function () {
        $user = User::first();
        MyJob::dispatch($user)->delay(5); // does not take effects
    // MyJob::dispatch($user)->delay(now()->addSeconds(5)); // even this
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

when I run job worker by calling php `artisan queue:work` all the jobs are processed immediately without delays but if I use: `php artisan queue:work --rest=5` everything is fine can anyone knows what's going on?

Normally I use: php artisan queue:work with the code provided but I noticed that the jobs are processed immediately with no delays even though I chained the delay method with the dispatch. Actually, the chained delay method does not take effect (exist or not = the same) the result I would like to get is the same as if you run:

```
php artisan queue:work --rest=5
```

which means to take a period let it be 5 seconds before processing the next job https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/46568

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/46582#issuecomment-1483803976